# NRV2B Decompression

Tags: c#, compression

I stumbled across the [UCL](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/ucl/) compression algorithm and I found it very interesting, so I decided to try to use it in a .NET project of mine but I couldn't find any library made for C# .NET, does anyone know if there is any around or anyone has ever made something similar?

I tried to download the source files downloaded from the above mentioned link and trying to import the sources in a vc++ project in order to try to build a dll to use it in c# but I encountered many problems due to complexity of the project itself, so I've been left without many option exept from asking here if anyone has ever tryied to made something similar to my goal.

Comment: Here is one of the close options *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* I think you nailed it

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks to pointed my this.. edited my question now to try to don't break any rule

Comment: Your link doesn't work also.. Yet even so, this is still too broad and off topic

Comment: @TheGeneral... hem the link is working nicely..

Comment: Some site to do with nasa rovers (on a badly designed page)

Comment: @TheGeneral man, I don't want to be rude but read carefully before saing I'm spamming.. http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/ucl/ maybe my bad..I'll change the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's written in C, so compile it as C. I would recommend linking directly to the resulting C library, as opposed to trying to convert it to C#.

Comment: thanks for your kind replay..I'll try that and let you know (honored to received an answer from you, looking forward to hear good news from the Low Density Supersonic Decelerator project)